# I am going to send email but the error says the failure to send email what's wrong in my code

Tags: c#, email, smtp, email-attachments, smtpclient

```
var userClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email_sender", "sender_password"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
userClient.Send("email_sender", "email_reciver", "body", "subject");
```

there is the code that i use,where is the problem?!

Comment: What is the actual Exception message you get?

Comment: i worked at code the error change, it says:"Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required."

Comment: There are two reasons for error 1) You are not using the correct SMTP setting for the email server.  You need to check the email server web page to see the SMTP settings.  2) The FROM address account must match the credentials.

Comment: but the code worked for 2weeks!!

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise updating your SmtpClient setup to set the DeliveryMethod and UserDefaultCredentials properties:

```
var userClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
{
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email_sender", "sender_password")
};

userClient.Send("email_sender", "email_reciver", "body", "subject");
```

I have seen in the past that if you do not set the DeliveryMethod, you will get an authentication issue.

I would also check that the email_sender and email_password credentials are correct.

Comment: thanks dude the code just worked thanks

Comment: Great!  Glad you got it working .